# Extract headers for Glide in a Utils class

Tags: android, android-glide

So I have the following logic in my class to load an image using Glibe library:

```
   GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url, new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                .addHeader("Auth", authToken)
                .addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
                .build());

        Glide.with(imgVw.getContext())
                .load(glideUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(placeholder)
                .into(imgVw);
```

This block of code I use it in many places so for that reason I want to extract just the part with LazyHeaders in a *GlideUtils* class.
This is what I have so far:

GlideUtils:

```
public class GlideUtils {

public GlideUtils() {
    initGlideHeaders();
}

private LazyHeaders.Builder initGlideHeaders() {
    return new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                .addHeader("Auth", authToken)
                .addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent));
} 
}
```

So then in my first class I will have :

```
  GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url, new GlideUtils()).build());
```

But I get an error on the line above that it is not correct. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you just create a `GlideUtils` instance and passing it to `GlideUrl`. But `GlideUrl` needs `LazyHeaders`.

So, update your GlideUtils file to create `LazyHeaders` directly like that :

```
public class GlideUtils {

    public static LazyHeaders glideHeaders() {
        return new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Auth", authToken)
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent).build();
    } 
}
```

And then use it to pass these Headers to your `GlideUrl` :

`GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url, GlideUtils.glideHeaders()).build());`